# Not called onLogoutSuccess on SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandle

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource; // get by Spring

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            // Here, you are making the public directory on the classpath root available without authentication (e..g. for css files)
            .antMatchers("/public/**", "/registration.html").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login.html")
            .successHandler((request, response, authentication) -> new DefaultRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, "/welcome"))
            .failureUrl("/login-error.html")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessHandler(new CustomLogoutSuccessHandler())
            .permitAll();
    }
}
```

Here is my custom handler: CustomLogoutSuccessHandler.java

```
public class CustomLogoutSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandler {
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(CustomLogoutSuccessHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.info("onLogoutSuccess:");
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login.html");
    }
}
```

In my template (`users.html`) I add a link like this:

```
<p align="center"><a th:href="@{/logout.html}">Logout</a></p>
```

But when click the logout link the method `onLogoutSuccess` is not call on my custom handler class.

Why?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59920286/cant-logout-by-custom-logout-handler/59929383#59929383